# Trying to cd in ssh heredoc

Tags: bash, variables, heredoc

I'm writing a script that start a ssh session and then perform screenshot on the remote server, the script is as follows.

```
numbah="$1"
. . . . 
# Taking the screenshot
ssh -x ${INPUT_USER}@nano-machine /bin/bash <<- EOF
  cd /tmp
  mkdir --parents -- temp_img && cd -- $_
  DISPLAY=:0 scrot "Screenshot-${numbah}_%d-%m-%Y.png"
  echo "first arg is $1 $1 $1"
EOF
```

The code block seems to be producing an error, causing `scrot` to fail.

```
/bin/bash: line 2: cd: /bin/bash: Not a directory
```

But if I quote the `EOF`, there will be no errors at all— except the variable will not be expanding, which is crucial to this script.

How to get rid of the error whilst keeping the variable intact/expandable ?

Comment: How can you `cd` to a script? `$_` is the script location, it's not a directory. Where do you want to `cd`?

Comment: Is this helpful for you? [Is it possible to send a HEREDOC over ssh to a remote host from inside a script running locally?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/187960)

Comment: @KamilCuk I was using this [method to combine `mkdir` and `cd`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/125459)...

Comment: T|hen why not just `mkdir -p temp_img; cd temp_img`? Well, you can `mkdir -p temp_img; cd "\$_"`, but really, I find just writing it more verbose.

Comment: @kvantour Nope, the effect is same as putting quote around `EOF`.

Comment: @Johnny, I think you need to get rid of `/bin/bash` in your ssh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to get rid of the error whilst keeping the variable intact/expandable ?

Disable expanding of this particular variable. Remember about quotes.

```
ssh -x ${INPUT_USER}@nano-machine /bin/bash <<- EOF
  cd /tmp
  mkdir --parents -- temp_img && cd -- "\$_"
  DISPLAY=:0 scrot "Screenshot-${numbah}_%d-%m-%Y.png"
  echo "first arg is $1 $1 $1"
EOF
```

But I really find that for complicated scripts it's easier to pass data as arguments and have the script not expand at all:

```
ssh -x ${INPUT_USER}@nano-machine /bin/bash -- "$numbah" <<-'EOF'
  cd /tmp
  mkdir --parents -- temp_img && cd -- "$_"
  DISPLAY=:0 scrot "Screenshot-${1}_%d-%m-%Y.png"
  echo "first arg is $1 $1 $1"
EOF
```